# Getting wrong result for FIND function of map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dictionary, stl

The method fails to find the char* array passed to it even though it is present in map.
When I replaced char* with std::string in map. Code works fine.

```
static void CreateTranslationMap();
static UString FindTranslatedString(char* propertyName);
static std::map<char*,UString> TranslationMap ;

static void CreateTranslationMap()
{
     UString engString("TextAlignmentPosition");
     char* transString= MSGTXT("TextAlignmentPosition");

    TranslationMap.insert(std::pair<char*,UString>(transString,engString));
}



UString FindTranslatedString(char* propertyName)
{
    UString NotFound("CannotFind");
    std::map<char*, UString>::iterator itr;
    itr = TranslationMap.begin();
    itr = TranslationMap.find(propertyName);
    if(itr!= TranslationMap.end())
    {
        return itr->second;
    }
    else if(itr== TranslationMap.end())
    {
        return NotFound;
    }

}
```

Comment: When using char * you are comparing pointers and not strings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your own custom comparator for comparing pointer to `char`

Use:

```
struct cmp_c_string
{
   bool operator()(char const *lhs, char const *rhs) const
   {
      return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
   }
};

std::map<char*,UString, cmp_c_string > TranslationMap ;
```

Comment: Ah the classic mistake. I made this a few months back =)
Can add [this info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) too:

**Compare**

A binary predicate that takes two element keys as arguments and returns a bool. The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this type and a and b are key values, shall return true if a is considered to go before b in the strict weak ordering the function defines.

Comment: It works for me, thanks! In my case I use const char* as key in a map.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when doing comparison for equality the map uses `<`.

When the `Key` of the map is `char*` you are doing comparisons of pointers (not the C-String). So you are testing to see if one pointer is less than the other pointer (ie comparing the address).

When the `Key` of the map is `std::string` you using the `operator<` that is defined for `std::string`, which actually compares the characters in the string to determine which is less than the other.

As the std::map is a template it actually takes more parameters to define how it works. The third parameters is the comparison function (which defaults to less `std::less<K>` which is usually `operator<`).

So you can use char* you just need a custom comparator operator.

```
bool comparitor(char const* lhs, char const* rhs)
{
     return (test for less than or some other strict weak function);
}
std::map<char*, UString, comparitor>  myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this behavior because you use pointer to string literal which is different every time you create such a pointer. So, for example, you create 2 pointers:

```
char* p1 = "Hello world!";
char* p2 = "Hello world!";
```

While content to which p1 and p2 point is identical the pointers, themselves, are different. So `p1 != p2`, and you trying to store pointer in the map. You should use std::string instead or have global constants pointers which you'd use everywhere; something like:

```
const char* const c_transString = MSGTXT("TextAlignmentPosition"); 
...
TranslationMap.insert(std::pair<char*,UString>(c_transString, engString));
...
FindTranslatedString(c_transString)
```

Answer (score 0):

when using char *, it just compare address.

```
char a[] = "hi";
char b[] = "hi";
char *c = a;
char *d = b;
```

c & d are different.(c != d) If you want to compare string, you should use strcmp.

But when using string, it overwrites "==" operation.
So you can just compare using "=="

```
string a = "hi";
string b = "hi";
```

a & b are same. (a == b)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace char* to const char* because the map data type always take the string in const form . I took your example and it is running in my terminal. So the new code is :

```
  #include<iostream>

   using namespace std;
   static void CreateTranslationMap();
   static string FindTranslatedString(const char* propertyName);
   static std::map<const char*,string> TranslationMap ;

  static void CreateTranslationMap()
   {
      string engString("TextAlignmentPosition");
      const char* transString= ("1");
      TranslationMap.insert(std::pair<const char*,string>(transString,engString));
   }


   string FindTranslatedString(const char* propertyName)
    {
        string NotFound("CannotFind");
        std::map<const char*, string>::iterator itr;
       itr = TranslationMap.begin();
       itr = TranslationMap.find(propertyName);
        if(itr!= TranslationMap.end())
        {
            return itr->second;
        }
       else if(itr== TranslationMap.end())
      {
         return NotFound;
       }

  }

 int main() 
  {

    CreateTranslationMap();
    string s =FindTranslatedString("1");
    cout<<s<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
```